# jQuery Autocomplete from external server fails

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Hi I am using the [jQuery Autocomplete Library](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (for lack of a better word) to try and implement a basic autocomplete feature on a page I have been working on. I have managed to, by basically using a modified version of the example code on that page, get the autocomplete to work by taking the json data from a static html page in the same folder. That worked fine. Now I am trying to get the data from a python script, which is implimented locally on google app engine, that spits out json data.

Here is some example data of raw input onto the page:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

I have printed the data multiple ways to verify that the data format should be correct (sorry, I do not know of any sure fire ways to test if it is valid json data).

Now for the code! this is the actual function that handles the auto-complete feature:

```
function suggest(textbox_data){
    $(textbox_data).autocomplete({
        source : function (request, response) 
        {
            var source_url = "http://localhost:8081/developers/add/jqueryResponse";
            //var data = "hello world"

            $.ajax({
                url: source_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) { 
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The reason I am putting everything into a function is because I am dynamically generating the text boxes. Just to make everything clear, here is the line where the text box is added. If anybody really wants I can add all the code for the textbox genoration, but I am pretty sure that is not the problem.

```
$('#buttondiv').append('<div><label>Textbox #'+$counter+'</label><input type="text" name="textbox[]" class="textbox" value="" id="country" onkeyup="suggest(this);"/><div id="testdiv"></div></div>');
```

Now for the error message! When I run the script in Firefox (Chrome was being a female dog when it comes to using the $.ajax feature locally) I get an error from firebug when trying to access the webpage containing the JSON data:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/developers/add/jqueryResponse 200 136ms   jquery.min.js (line 16)
```

On line 16 in the file, basically contains everything in the script so it does not really narrow it down. Anyways, please help!

Comment: Does your python script allows GET access to JSON data? What error did you get in Firebug?

Comment: Yes it allows GET access, But I am not sure if the same applies to JSON data. I don't Know how to check either so, I guess my follow up question would be how would I check that?

Comment: also! the error is the last "code block" in my post

Comment: You can try `url: source_url,type:"POST" , datatype:'json'` and see if it makes any diffrence

Comment: I get the same error except it says POST at the begining. I may also remind you that the error is most likely refearing to somewhere in the autocomplete jquery file.

Comment: Also, after adding an alert("test"); to the success: {} section, I found that it is never triggered, so the error is happening when trying to access the page with the json

Answer (score 0):

Your Success handler is incomplete. Have a look at the source code of [Demo page.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html)

The success handler should look like this:

```
success: function( data ) {

        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) 
{

return {label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,Value: item.name}
                        }));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: ok thank you! I will add that to my code. But I will also reminde you that I managed to use the same code except the url was changed to "test.html" which was a local html document on my computer with just a sample list of json data, So I am not sure If I need that (granted I will still add it)

Comment: if above doesn't work, just add `beforeSend: function (x) {

                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) { x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8"); }'

                    },` to your original code.

Comment: Until you mention what error you are getting it's hard to suggest what your really need to do.

Comment: I mentioned the error! the last code block! that was copy pasted from firebug

Comment: Also, after adding an alert("test"); to the success: {} section, I found that it is never triggered, so the error is happening when trying to access the page with the json

Comment: I am disputed to how to respond to all this... The problem was fixed by adding my jquery code as well to my server. But I want to give this the checkmark becuase it is the way I should be doing things.